# How do I make a top level xsd:element optional when it contains a complexType?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this XSD element defined:

```
<xsd:element name="CU_FIRST_NAME">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            The first name of the customer that is getting billed for the order
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

I know this could be replaced by a single element, but I have a more complex element (a sequence) that I need to make optional.

Is there a way to make a first-child (i.e. just below `<xsd:schema>` in the hierarchy) element optional?

To be clear, I'd like to make the entire `CU_FIRST_NAME` node, along with all of its children, optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up realizing that the element I was using was actually a ref within a higher level object.

The way I solved this was thus:

Original code:

```
<xsd:element ref="CU_FIRST_NAME"/>
```

New code:

```
<xsd:element ref="CU_FIRST_NAME" minOccurs="0"/>
```

So, really I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: that is what I said.LOL.  I figured that you had to be inside of another element. otherwise it wouldn't be much of an XML Document with no Elements.  please mark my answer if it helped you out.  thanks

Comment: Actually your question was quite reasonable, pleased you found the answer. Optionality/cardinality is a property of the element particle, not the element declaration - that is, it's a property of the relationship between a complex type and an element that appears in the content model defined by that complex type.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
      <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

use `minOccurs="0"` in the very first element. this will make it so that if you select the top you have to select the rest. but if you put that in the children as well then they will all be optional.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not able to put the minOccurs as an attribute in the top level element.